# Может ли столбец таблицы ссылаться на эту же таблицу?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, реляционная-модель

В описании задания есть описание таблицы:

```sql
-- Таблица каталога продуктов
create table catalog (
    cid number primary key, -- id раздела
    par_cid number references catalog, -- ссылка на родительский раздел
    rname varchar2(400), -- наименование раздела
    rdescr varchar2(4000), -- описание
    rcdate date -- дата создания
);
```

Правильно ли написан код создания таблицы `catalog` в строке:

```
par_cid number references catalog, -- ссылка на родительский раздел
```

Может ли столбец таблицы `catalog` ссылаться на эту же таблицу `catalog`?

Comment: *Может ли поле таблицы catalog ссылаться на эту же таблицу catalog?* Да, может. Только не на таблицу. Это краткая запись ссылки на ключевое поле указанной таблицы (нестандарт, фича Оракла). Обычный self-reference, хранение дерева в parent-child форме.

Comment: А вот ссылки на `units` и `persons` - это ссылки в никуда в рамках показанного кода. А т.к. `product` не создастся, то и ссылка на неё в `records` - тоже в никуда.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Может ли столбец таблицы `catalog` ссылаться на эту же таблицу `catalog`?

Да, может. Это ссылка таблицы на саму себя для хрнения иерархических структур данных.

Точнее, будет создан внешний ключ (*foreign key=FK*), ссылающийся (*references*) на первичный ключ (*primary key=PK*) этой же таблицы. Последний можно по умолчанию не указывать, так как он гарантированно только один в таблице.

Полная запись (рекомендованный способ записи) выглядела бы так:

```
create table catalog (
    cid number primary key, 
    par_cid number, 
    rname varchar2(400), 
    rdescr varchar2(4000), 
    rcdate date,
    constraint fk_catalog foreign key (par_cid) references catalog (cid))
/
```

Простейший пример данных и типичный запрос с ними:

```
insert into catalog 
    select 1, null, 'catalog1', 'main catalog', sysdate from dual union all
    select 2,    1, 'catalog2', 'under catalog1', sysdate from dual union all
    select 3,    1, 'catalog3', 'under catalog1', sysdate from dual
/

select  cid, par_cid, rname name, lpad (' ', (level-1)*4)||rdescr descr
from catalog 
start with par_cid is null
connect by par_cid = prior cid
/

       CID    PAR_CID NAME     DESCR                           
---------- ---------- -------- --------------------------------
         1            catalog1 main catalog                    
         2          1 catalog2     under catalog1              
         3          1 catalog3     under catalog1
```

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение с примером)

Comment: Рад был помочь! В следующий раз не включайте в вопрос ничего лишнего, за это, думаю, кто-то минус проставил.